# How do I apply assumptions to a table of functions

Tags: list-manipulation, assumptions, tensors

I have a table, really its a tensor but anyways I would like to apply an assumption to it, i.e. `1 - 2 phi[t,x,y,z] == 1` and have it print the tensor after it has applied this assumption, how do I do this?
Here is my code

```
glab := {{-(1 + 2 phi[t, x, y, z]), 0, 0, 
   0}, {0, (1 - 2 phi[t, x, y, z]), 0, 0}, {0, 
   0, (1 - 2 phi[t, x, y, z]), 0}, {0, 0, 
   0, (1 - 2 phi[t, x, y, z])}}

guap := {{1/(-(1 + 2 phi[t, x, y, z])), 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1/(
   1 - 2 phi[t, x, y, z]), 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1/(1 - 2 phi[t, x, y, z]), 
   0}, {0, 0, 0, 1/(1 - 2 phi[t, z, y, z])}}

Gama := Table[(1/2)*
   Sum[guap[[a, c]] (D[glab[[a, b]], var[[i]]] + 
       D[glab[[a, i]], var[[b]]] - D[glab[[b, i]], var[[a]]]), {a, 1.,
      4.}], {c, 1., 4.}, {b, 1., 4.}, {i, 1., 4.}]

var := {t, x, y, z}

Rabiv := Table[
  D[Gama[[a, b, v]], var[[i]]] - D[Gama[[a, b, i]], var[[v]]] + 
   Sum[Gama[[a, o, i]]*Gama[[o, b, v]], {o, 1., 4.}] - 
   Sum[Gama[[a, o, v]]*Gama[[o, b, i]], {o, 1., 4.}], {a, 1., 4.}, {b,
    1., 4.}, {i, 1., 4.}, {v, 1., 4.}]
Simplify[Rabiv, Assumptions -> {(1/(1 - 2 phi[t, x, y, z])) == 1}]
```

This prints the tensor Rabiv, but it does not apply simplifying assumptions. I also tried something like

```
Simplify[Rabiv,Assumptions->{(1/(1-2phi[t,x,y,z]))==1}]
```

Same issue, prints the table but won't apply assumption.

Comment: I edited my question to include my original code

Comment: Changing `Simplify[Rabiv, Assumptions -> {(1/(1 - 2 phi[t, x, y, z])) == 1}]` to `Simplify[Rabiv,1 - 2 phi[t, x, y, z]==1]` reduces the size of the output by about 1/2. Mathematica sometimes doesn't see the same things in denominators that a bright student would be able to see. Even with my change there are still things in denominators that it hasn't replaced and I'm fiddling to see if I can get rid of those.

Comment: Thank you! When applying multiple assumptions would I just type something like ```Simplify[Rabiv, Assumptions -> {(1 - 2 phi[t, x, y, z]) == 1,1+2phi[t,x,y,z]==1}]```?

Comment: Your assumption is equivalent to the replacement rule `{phi[t, x, y, z] -> 0}`

Comment: I just want Mathematica to replace ```(1/(1-2phi[t,x,y,z]))``` with 1, I dont want it to imply that phi is zero because I'm using it as an approximation to first order.

Comment: @Bill so could you provide me with a sample code that worked when you made those assumptions? I still cant get it to get rid of the terms I want it to.